# How to use github nuget packages on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2019, nuget-package, github-package-registry

I try to learn Github action and packages. So, I create a sample nuget package and successfully created. However I could not use it.

I follow this step;

1. Options > Nuget Package Manager > Package Sources
2. Click add button write organization name and add package source address like that:
   [image]
3. After that Visual Studio doesn't ask me any credential for this address.
4. If there is no credential, I will expect to an error. And I got it.

   [github] Failed to retrieve metadata from source 'https://nuget.pkg.github.com/[OrganizationName]/query?q=&skip=0&take=26&prerelease=false&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
     Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
5. Then, I decide to some credential like explained in [github documentation](https://help.github.com/en/packages/using-github-packages-with-your-projects-ecosystem/configuring-dotnet-cli-for-use-with-github-packages#authenticating-to-github-packages).
6. My nuget.config file:
   [image]
7. However still I get Unauthorized error. And also when I click the error link gettin a message like that:

> {"errors":[{"code":"Your token has not been granted the required
>   scopes to execute this query. The 'id' field requires one of the
>   following scopes","message":" ['read:packages'], but your token has
>   only been granted the: [''] scopes. Please modify your token's scopes
>   at: https://github.com/settings/tokens."}]}

but I already have a token with read/write package credential.
[image]

8. All that fails and I try to another way. I add credential information to Windows Credential Manager. Eveything still same.
   [image]

So, how I add and use my private nuget packages?

Comment: If you use encrypted passwords,, you should add `<add key="Password" value="..." />` .Hint from [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#packagesourcecredentials). Besdies, please put `nuget.config` file under solution folder which exists `xxx.sln` file. Then close VS Instance, then restart your project again. It needs to restart VS to enable the new `nuget.config` file.

Comment: And if does not work, please added all Repo scopes and all User scopes for your token. And then restart your project.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT Thanks for restart idea. I restart computer and problem solved :) Probably why is all visual studio instances restarted. I already have a github issue in Visual Studio (https://github.com/github/VisualStudio/issues/2521) so I am not sure which issue rease what.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How to use github nuget packages on Visual Studio 2019

**First**, make sure that your credential info is correct on the `nuget.config` file.

I found your document suggest you should put a new `nuget.config` file to your solution. This `nuget.config` file is a local action file, it will act on any projects in the current subdirectory and below the current level. You can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior#config-file-locations-and-uses).

In this way, you should restart VS Instance to enable this new `nuget.config` file.

**-------Global nuget.config--------**

**However**, from your description and first picture, you used the global `nuget.config` file. And UI's info stores under global `nuget.config` file.

If you want to config this gihub package source for all the projects on your PC, you should config it on the global `nuget.config` file.

And the first picture which you provided indicates that you used in the global file(`C:\Users\xxx(current user)\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config`).

This function also needs restart VS to enable the new `nuget.config` file.

**Suggestion**

1. please add your content of the file into `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config`.
2. restart VS Instance or restart PC to enable this new `nuget.config` file. It is designed by that.

Answer (score 15):

I just faced this problem today with VS 19.

When adding a new source for Nuget packages as shown below, i got prompted a first time for User and Password

[image: Add nuget package source]

I did the mistake of entering my github password as password. Instead you should create a token under your github settings as shown below and enter the token itself instead of your account's password.

[image: Generate token]

In my case, I selected the following options when creating the token

[image: Token options]

VS 19 unfortunately did not prompt another time for credentials and kept showing the error message:

[github] Failed to retrieve metadata from source ... .Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).

To change this parameters on Windows, open Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager as shown below:

[image: Web credentials]

Click on Edit, and paste the **access token** you just created on github as password. Scroll down the list of credentials. In my case, I needed to change the password in a second place as well.

[image: Second web credentials]

Comment: Seems like it was a recent change on GitHub since plain `password` worked before

Answer (score 14):

It is not an easy task, but here is the solution (after 2 days of struggling)

1. First generate PAT (Personal Access Token) in Github 
   [Follow these steps to generate a PAT](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token#creating-a-token)
   **Very important to select the read:packages options**
   [image] 
   **Github will show you the PAT for ONLY ONE TIME, So make sure to copy it to save place, otherwise, you have to generate it again**
2. Now with PAT in your hand, Add `Nuget.Config` file to your project 
   [image] 
   The content of the file should be like following

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <configuration>
       <packageSources>
           <clear />
           <add key="github" value="https://nuget.pkg.github.com/OWNER/index.json" />
       </packageSources>
       <packageSourceCredentials>
           <github>
               <add key="Username" value="USERNAME" />
               <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="TOKEN" />
           </github>
       </packageSourceCredentials>
   </configuration>
   ```
3. You must replace:

   - USERNAME with the name of your user account on GitHub.
   - TOKEN with your personal access token **(the token you generated in Step 1)**.
   - OWNER with the name of the user or organization account that owns the repository containing your project.
4. You must restart Visual Studio or even Restart the PC **This is important**

After that open the Terminal and copy and paste (maybe with some modifications) the statement that Github give to you to install the package

[image]

*Now you are ready to get the Package*.

---

**UPDATE**

> How to configure github nuget packages for teams?

Configure the `nuget.config` using *environment variables*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="NuGet official package source" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="Github" value="https://nuget.pkg.github.com/OWNER/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <Github>
      <add key="Username" value="%GITHUB_PACKAGE_USER_NAME%" />
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="%GITHUB_PACKAGE_TOKEN%" />
    </Github>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

The `GITHUB_PACKAGE_USER_NAME` and `GITHUB_PACKAGE_TOKEN` can be anything you want.

Now, each team member should configure their **user** environment variables:

- `GITHUB_PACKAGE_USER_NAME`: team member github user name
- `GITHUB_PACKAGE_TOKEN`: team member Personal Access Token (PAT)

With those configurations, Visual Studio will be able to query and download packages, **assuming** the *team member* has access to the OWNER package repository.

> How to restore github nuget packages in **github actions** workflows?

With the previous `NuGet.config` configured, you need to change your workflow passing the required environment variables, like so:

```
- name: Restore dependencies
  env:
    GITHUB_PACKAGE_USER_NAME: ${{ github.actor }}
    GITHUB_PACKAGE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.RESTORE_ORGANIZATION_PACKAGES }}
  run: dotnet restore ./src
```

Since you can't pass your PAT, you need to configure a github secret (either for the [repository](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets#creating-encrypted-secrets-for-a-repository) or the [organization](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets#creating-encrypted-secrets-for-an-organization)). In the above example, I created a secret named `RESTORE_ORGANIZATION_PACKAGES` with `read:packages` permission at the repository level.

Comment: what if the repository is **shared** with the team? how can each team member configure its own PAT and add to the `nuget.config`? it seems wrong to have credentials in the `nuget.config`, which is shared and committed to the repository

Comment: @JobaDiniz yes, I agree with you, it did not make sense to me either, I think maybe the best solution, in this case, could be not adding the `NuGet.config` file to the repository, and keeping it local for each machine, not the best of solution, I know, but I could not think of something better

Comment: figured out a solution for teams. You can specify *environment variables* in the `nuget.config`. So, each team member needs to have 2 env vars (`%github_user_name%` and `%github_pat%`) configured in their Windows/Linux/Mac.